# Python assigning two variables on one line

Tags: python, int, self

```
class Domin():
    def __init__(self , a, b) :
        self.a=a , self.b=b

    def where(self):
        print 'face : ' , self.a , "face : " ,self.b

    def value(self):
        print self.a + self.b

d1=Domin(1 , 5)   

d1=Domin(20 , 15)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    d1=Domin(1 , 5)
  File "test2.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.a=a , self.b=b
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: You should use `;` instead of `,` in `__init__`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You cannot put two statements on one line like that. Your code is being evaluated like this:

```
self.a = (a, self.b) = b
```

Either use a semicolon (on second thought, don't do that):

```
self.a = a; self.b = b
```

Or use sequence unpacking:

```
self.a, self.b = a, b
```

Or just split it into two lines:

```
self.a = a
self.b = b
```

I would do it the last way.

Comment: +1 for sequence unpacking. Definitely can be useful to save space when instantiating several variables to something like `0`, such as counters

Comment: @br1ckb0t: If they all have the same value, you can just do `a = b = c = 0`.