# 'int' object is not iterable when trying to assign loop index

Tags: python, loops, variable-assignment

This is really strange, please take a loop at code snippet below, when i remove `num=i`, all works fine but with it, it is causing iteration issue.

**Error code**

```
In [17]: prim_list=[]
    ...: for i in range(2,101):
    ...:     print i
    ...:     num=i,count=0        # line with issue
    ...:     for j in range(1,i/2):
    ...:         div=j
    ...:         if(num%div==0):
    ...:             count=count+1
    ...:     if(count==1):
    ...:         prim_list.append(num)
    ...:
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-a8dd2a52322e> in <module>()
      2 for i in range(2,101):
      3     print i
----> 4     num=i,count=0
      5     for j in range(1,i/2):
      6         div=j

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Working fine**

```
In [19]: prim_list=[]
    ...: for i in range(2,101):
    ...:     count=0              # notice num=i assignment is removed
    ...:     for j in range(1,i/2):
    ...:         div=j
    ...:         if(num%div==0):
    ...:             count=count+1
    ...:     if(count==1):
    ...:         prim_list.append(num)
    ...: print "done"
    ...:
done
```

What i am not understanding is why the assignment is causing the loop iteration error!!??

any help is appreciated!

Comment: `num=i,count=0` is a single statement, meaning `num=(i,count)=0`. Unpacking assignment doesn't work with integers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters may be i put the question incorrectly but i am definitely trying to understand the wrong error it throws, how is python doing it internally that the assignment and error statement dont match!!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16747599/2301450

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a chained assignment:

```
num=i,count=0
```

is

```
num = (i, count) = 0
```

Where `num = 0` and `(i, count) = 0` are assigned. Because `0` is not an iterable of length 2, it can't be  assigned to a tuple of targets.

Use

```
num, count = i, 0
```

or

```
num = i
count = 0
```

instead.

Comment: ohh man...python never ends surprising with its simplicity..thanks, will accept in due time ( *but in my defense, question wasn't that dumb to get 2 downvotes* :D ) !

Comment: Or, `num = i; count = 0` (note semicolon rather than comma, which makes it two separate statements)

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is you are misinterpreting the comma operator. Unlike C, it does not allow you to do multiple statements. What it is doing is destructuring assignment, for example:

```
a, b = [1, 2]
# a == 1; b == 2
```

So, `num=i,count=0` is more like:

```
num = i, count = 0
# equivalent to:
num = 0
i, count = 0
```

Which doesn't make sense.

The semicolon (`;`) does what you intended, but go with a newline:

```
num = i
count = 0
```