# Initializing variables side by side

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

i=3,b=5

Why can't I run the above line in python? It says can't assign to literals error. It is not an error in Java or C++.

Comment: Ah, but `i,b = 3,5` will work

Comment: Java and C++ are different languages from Python. If every language had the same syntax there would only be one language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python assigning two variables on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747599/python-assigning-two-variables-on-one-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big-picture answer to "why not?" is that the designer of the language was not fond of that syntax and preferred that programmers write

```
i, b = 3, 5
```

The *technical* reason why this is not allowed, and the explanation for your error message, can be found by [reading the official grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html).

You can also experiment to see what the meaning of your phrase would be by inspecting the Python AST. Run this:

```
import ast
print(ast.dump(ast.parse("i=3,b")))
```

You get

```
Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='i', ctx=Store())], value=Tuple(elts=[Num(n=3), Name(id='b', ctx=Load())], ctx=Load()))])
```

So just writing `i=3,b` is an assignment of the tuple `(3,b)` to the variable `i`. Now you *can* write

```
i = b = 3
```

which assigns 3 to both `i` and `b`. But if you wrote

```
i = 3, b = 5
```

Then you would be trying to assign 5 to the tuple `(3,b)` which is not allowed.

This is the way Python is. The designer of Python wanted it to be that way. And he is the [boss](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BDFL).